# Sometimes I don't know which classes certain methods belong to. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, c#, class, refactoring

Say there is a simple game where I have a class called `Player`, which holds all the information that a player would have, e.g. `name`, `xPosition`, `yPosition`, `width`, `height`, etc.

The `Player` class has also has methods associated with it that describe what a `Player` can do, e.g. `move()`, `draw()`, etc.

In the game, I need to be able to know when a `Player` collides with *any* other object in the game like a wall, ceiling or other world object.

I can go about this in 2 ways:

**Create a class like `CollisionDetecter` that has a method like `detectCollision()`. Include an instance of this class in the `Player` class and call the `detectCollision()` method when appropriate**

**Rationale:**

- Detecting collisions isn't really an intrinsic property of a `Player` like it's `xPosition`, `yPosition` or `name` is, so it doesn't belong in this class.
- Less clutter in the `Player` class. (Does this count?)

**Create a method like `detectCollision()` in the `Player` class which checks to see if the `Player` has hit anything**

**Rationale:**

- Detecting collisions is something that a `Player` does so the `detectCollision()` method should be directly in the `Player` class.
- Only Players need to be able to detect collisions, so why should I create another whole class with just 1 method for this? Why not just include it as a method in the `Player` class?

I feel like I'm always struggling with debates like this.

Which method is the most appropriate and why? Are both of these bad and should I be doing something else?

Comment: Your question seems to be **subject to opinion**.  [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In General :-

Sometimes, its better to start with it on the player class and see what the consequences are.   Refactoring is ultimately your friend, if you see that the method you are writing is needing things not really related to Player, then you start working out a new design.

In Specific :-

Perhaps Player is a GameObject,   and Collision Detection is a Generic concept that determines collisions between game objects.

Perhaps a player is not really a class,  perhaps Player is just a GameObject with a Movement Strategy,  ie Player really is composed of more fundamental aspects of a game.